# How to link build result of "plain React"/node app with release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

To try to make it short, I have a React application that's build on Azure DevOps Build Pipeline like so

```
trigger:
  - Release

queue:
  name: Hosted
  demands: npm

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
  npm ci
  npm run build
  displayName: 'Do npm ci and build'
```

This does what the build would do locally too. Locally the results of build go to `build` directory (unzipped).

Now when I try to create release pipeline there isn't an artifact to be found using `Azure Deploy Web Service` task.

If I try to add [PublishPipelineArtifact@0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact) to the build pipeline to create a publication, the YAML editor just tells *string does not match pattern...* and doesn't let save the definition.

I suppose I should zip the contents of the generated `build` directory, but what would be the right way? Also, Is using the `Azure App Service Deploy` task the right way to deploy Azure WebApp? It works for ASP.NET Core apps so it finds the code drop artefact (zipped) and deploys it.

<edit: Adding

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@0
  inputs:
  artifactName: 'drop'
  targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/build'
```

Can actually be saved and the build run. Though it errors with

> 2019-01-25T22:42:27.6896518Z ##[section]Starting:
>   PublishPipelineArtifact 2019-01-25T22:42:27.6898909Z
>   ============================================================================== 2019-01-25T22:42:27.6898962Z Task         : Publish Pipeline Artifact
>   2019-01-25T22:42:27.6899006Z Description  : Publish Pipeline Artifact
>   2019-01-25T22:42:27.6899034Z Version      : 0.139.0
>   2019-01-25T22:42:27.6899062Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>   2019-01-25T22:42:27.6899090Z Help         : Publish a local directory
>   or file as a named artifact for the current pipeline.
>   2019-01-25T22:42:27.6899137Z
>   ============================================================================== 2019-01-25T22:42:28.0499917Z ##[error]Path not exist: D:\a\1\a\build
>   2019-01-25T22:42:28.0708878Z ##[section]Finishing:
>   PublishPipelineArtifact

< edit 2: It appears removing the `/build` does the trick. Feels a tad odd since this is what's produced locally. It doesn't produce a zip file which is expected by the release job, namely Azure App Service Deploy.

Have to examine this problem later today (two o'clock at night here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was another problem: The script ran only `npm ci` and didn't run the building part. Separating it to two different steps made the difference. It appears `PublishPipelineArtifact@0` in this case isn't an ideal option if I'd like to have the results as zipped to the staging area.

A currently working solution seem to be

```
resources:
- repo: self

trigger:
- Release

queue:
  name: Hosted
  demands: npm

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
    displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
  npm ci    
  displayName: 'npm ci'

- script: |
  npm run build
  displayName: 'npm run build'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/artifact.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
```

Maybe this can be simplified, but works for now and is flexible, it feels.